# How to run a shell script over ssh with resource(.txt files) in one machine and the script in another machine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, server, fedora

I want to run a shell script using SSH which takes resource from other machine while the script is in some other machine, all on the same network. I don't want to copy the resource to the local machine.

Note: The shell script takes .txt file as input

Comment: So remote script has to take text file as input from some other remote machine. Right?

Comment: @mario23 please edit your question to add the information from your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have script.sh on server1 and file.txt on server2, you can connect through ssh to server1, and then do:

```
[user@server1]$ ssh user@server2 "cd mydir && cat file.txt" | ./script.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 ssh USER_NAME@HOST_ADDRESS "BASH_SCRIPT_FILE_PATH"
```

You will need to provide password whenever required.

Comment: This one helps to run remote machine script.

Comment: I don't think this would be the exact answer to the question.

Comment: I have checked this and this seems to working accordingly. We placed script on one server and execute the same from another machine.

Answer (score 0):

If your script is in Machine A, you can't run that on Machine B without copying it over. First, copy the script over to Machine B using scp

```
[user@machineA]$ scp /path/to/script user@machineB:/home/user/path
```

Then, just run the script

```
[user@machineA]$ ssh user@machineB "/home/user/path/script"
```

This will work if you have given executable permission to the script.

OR

**Try this one..**

```
<hostA_shell_prompt>$ ssh user@hostB "ls -la"
```

That will prompt you for password, unless you have copied your hostA user's public key to the authorized_keys file on the home of user .ssh's directory. That will allow for passwordless authentication (if accepted as an auth method on the ssh server's configuration)

Answer (score 0):

I not fully understand your question. Other answers gave "How to run remote script?"

But i think question is Remote script has to take remote file, even I not sure about this

1. Login Remote PC using ssh.
2. Install `sshfs` if not installed .
3. Then mount other remote machine directory which has the file you want to use in script to    local directory. This can be done using `sshfs`
4. Then run the script with file from locally mounted directory
5. Then unmount the directory when you finished.

Somewhat large procedure.

[Mounting remote directory with sshfs](http://www.howtoforge.com/mounting-remote-directories-with-sshfs-on-ubuntu-11.10)

[man sshfs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sshfs)